# Finding all combinations for players in a tournament without duplicates

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

For a table soccer tournament I have the following request:

- There are two types of players A (Students) and B (Teachers). (For simplicity we assume the same number of A and B players). eg. 16 students and 16 teachers.
- The table soccer tournament should have as many rounds as possible
- A round means: Every player plays one game together with a teammate against two other players.
- For each round a player need a teammate he never played with before. A "new" player.
- The teammate must be of a different type (a student always plays with a teacher).
- Each player from the opposing team must be "new" as well (neither be a previous opponent nor a previous teammate).

Example: 
I am a student (player type A) and have a game with teacher T_John (player type B) as teammate. We play against a student S_Mike and a teacher T_James. After the game finished a new round starts. In this new round (and all upcomming rounds) I should not play with (or against) T_John, T_James or S-Mike anymore, neither as teammate nor as an opponent.

The idea is to meet as many new people during the tournament as possible.

I've created a first prototype where each player has a list of all players he never played with (or against) before. For each game, I now start with a list of all players and for each player select the next fitting player as teammate and the 2 opponents. While this works, the combinations are very limited. I don't know a way to get better and consistent results.

Here is this main routine in the Player class:

```
for (var i = 0; i < availablePlayers.length; i++) {
    var player = availablePlayers[i];
    if (player == this || player.hasPlayedWith(this))
        continue;

    if (!teamMate && player.type != this.type &&
          (!opponent1 || !player.hasPlayedWith(opponent1))) {
        teamMate = player;
        count++;
    }
    else if (!opponent1 && (!teamMate || !player.hasPlayedWith(teamMate))) {
        opponent1 = player;
        count++;
    }
    else if (opponent1 && !opponent2 &&
         player.type != opponent1.type &&
         !player.hasPlayedWith(opponent1)) {
       opponent2 = player;
       count++;
    }
    if (count == 3) {
        return [
          new Team(this, teamMate),
          new Team(opponent1, opponent2)
        ];
    }
}
```

Here is a fiddle with the whole prototype which visualizes the players, teams, games and rounds.
http://jsfiddle.net/q6e2pymL/

I'm pretty sure that there must be some kind of pattern or algorithm to calculate the best combinations. Ideas or suggestions?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please update those rules, because while the people who know what this algorithm is know what you're talking about, your description of it is _not_ clear enough =) Point 2 talks about "the tournament" without explanation, point 3's "random or defined logic" is not an "or". Your algorithm can prescribe using randomisation, making the random behaviour _be_ the defined logic. Point 4 needs rewriting, and point 5 makes no sense: both teams are opposing teams. And no, this isn't nit picking: when you describe an algorithm, one of the skills you need is to be able to precisely describe requirements.

Comment: I am confused on your point 5. You said there are type A and B, so it sounds like there are two opposing team A and B which can never change. But from your point 5, it sounds like players can interchange teams from the line "neither be a previous opponent nor a previous teammate". Please clarify on that

Comment: Thanks @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans and Kenta for your support. I've updated my question. Hope it is easier to understand.

Comment: @KentaNomoto thanks for your feedback. No, each team consists of a player of type A (student) and a player of type B (teacher). I hope the new explanation makes it clear.

Comment: I don't know if i will try so just a hint: generate all valid doubles (like in tennis), each generated double taking into account the previously generated doubles. you get a set S. From S, generate all possible rounds so C_|S|^8 per round, each round being a node, and link rounds together if no double is in both rounds. Then take the maximum clique out of that

Comment: @grodzi Thanks for the idea of generating all possible doubles first. I will try that. What does C_|S|^8 mean?

Comment: Combination of 8 amongst |S| (the number of doubles) idem 60*59*58*57*56*55*54*53/8! (if |S|==60)